# Opengl program not looping when window is focused

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

I'm having problems running my opengl 4 program. When the window is in focus, nothing appears to happen (even alt+f4 doesn't register until the window is out of focus).

If the window containing my program is in focus, then the main loop for my program stops executing (I checked using printf statements, within my while(true) loop, and the output stops completely when focused on the window). When the window is not focused, the program runs as expected (including mouse movements inside the window changing the camera direction).

I've narrowed it down to this line of code, which is executed within my mouse callback method

glfwSetCursorPos ( window, middleX, middleY);

If this is commented out, the program runs fine when in focus, but the mouse is no longer centred, so the camera logic no longer works.

I'm using 32 bit versions of glfw3 and glew.

This program has worked on other machines in the past. Is there any way to fix this without restructuring the code to poll the mouse input?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `glfwSetCursorPos()` inside your mouse callback, you can get to the situation that this creates a new mouse event, and after your callback exited, `glfwPollEvents()` will loop over the remaining events, so you effectively enter some endless loop here. You should just delay such actions after the input callbacks have been handled.

However, even with that approach, you will generate a new event for each frame, so that I suggest dropping the callback overhead alltogether and just quering the mouse position with `glfwGetCursorPos()` directly every frame.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm really confused as to why the code worked previously though. I couldn't find any mention of glfwSetCursorPos() in the version history page